# How would I get the text of a JLabel (with an icon) explaining what the label is by hovering over the label?

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jlabel

I want to see the text of JLabel when I hover over the label. The text explains what the label does in detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to set the text of the tooltip by calling: `setToolTipText()`

More about tooltips in the tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html

Answer (score 4):

If you want to retrieve the Tooltip then you should use something like this:

```
JLabel label;
...//initialize label, etc
String text = label.getToolTipText();
```

In case you are asking how to set the Tooltip then you should do the opposite:

```
JLabel label;
...//initialize label, etc
label.setToolTipText("this is the description of the label");
```

Comment: well in that case I misunderstood the question will edit to include the setting.