# How create a JLabel when I pass with mouse on the button

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouseenter

(JAVA) I would that when I move my mouse on a particular button I can read the function of this button like a Jlabel that it is created expressly for this event under the mouse position.
I think at this approach: 
1) capture mouseEvent and in particular MouseEntered
2) create a Jlabel and display it

I want know if exists another approach to do this or only my method. Anyone can help me?

Comment: This has been asked many times before, for example, please see this [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209514/how-would-i-get-the-text-of-a-jlabel-with-an-icon-explaining-what-the-label-is) which was used to close your question. And for more similar questions/answers, please check out this [search of this site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjava%5d%20%5bswing%5d%20mouse%20hover%20%20popup). In fact, this second link is the most important since it will introduce you to the search capabilities of this site and help reduce unnecessary duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to provide a [ToolTip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setToolTipText-java.lang.String-). The framework then takes care about the label and event handling.

Note: setToolTipText is a method of JControl, so this work with other controls as well.

Comment: yess! thank Puce it's exactly what I mean!